# How to get the list of segments, groups and the no.of repetitions of HL7 v2x msg by Hapi

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, hapi, hl7-v2

Regarding the message as below I would to get the list of segments, groups as respectively as well as the no.of repetitions count, the list of segments and subgroups inside of a group too. While I want to use Hapi-2.1 with Apache Camel.

```
MSH|^~\&|SENDERAPP|SENDERFAC|COVCDR|COVCDR|20130212221503||ORU^R01|1676326503009050|P|2.6
PID|1||MRN101||DOE^JOHN^A||20000101|M||W|1 Campus Martius^^Detroit^MI^48226||^227-7300||EN|S|||111-11-1111|||H 
PV1|1|U| 12E^1211^01||||1689885733^ORANGE TEAM, OMNI|||Med||||Tra|||99999999^SMITH^KEVIN^^^^MD|I|000000000000|YY|P||||||||||||||||||||Ac|||20130224080500||^F78520223|000000000^LA||^CM||||20130226020200|||| PICU|||^RESULT PERFORMED|||RES 
OBR|1|F78520223|1305611705^LA|0101301^COMPLETE BLOOD COUNT^COMPLETE BLOOD COUNT|||20130226010600|20130226020200||2632||||20130226014200||333333^GEORGE, BOB|||||0001305611705|20130226020200|||F||^^^20130226043000^^EA~^^^^^EA 
OBX|1|NM|0106550^WHITE BLOOD CELL COUNT^WHITE BLOOD CELL COUNT||7.9|10e9/L|4.3-11.0||||F|||20130226020200|34333^Kelly, Bacon^^00010033^MOLIS XE2|RES 
OBX|2|NM|0104650^RBCx10e12^RBCx10e12||4.09|10e12/L|4.53-5.73|L|||F|||20130226020200|34333^Kelly, Bacon^^00010033^MOLIS XE2|RES 
OBX|3|NM|0102150^HEMOGLOBIN^HEMOGLOBIN||12.9|g/dL|13.6-17.4|L|||F|||20130226020200|34333^Kelly, Bacon^^00010033^MOLIS XE2|RES 
OBX|4|NM|0102100^HEMATOCRIT^HEMATOCRIT||37.5|%|40.7-50.8|L|||F|||20130226020200|34333^Kelly, Bacon^^00010033^MOLIS XE2|RES 
OBX|5|NM|0103500^MEAN CORPUSCULAR VOLUME^MEAN CORPUSCULAR VOLUME||91.7|fL|81.6-96.8||||F|||20130226020200|34333^Kelly, Bacon^^00010033^MOLIS XE2|RES 
NTE|1||Test performed at Tulsa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `PipeParser` to [parse](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/base/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/parser/PipeParser.html#parse(java.lang.String)) the message.

In this case you will get an [ORU_R01](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/v26/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/v26/message/ORU_R01.html) object.